# How can I change the Slider text in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, slider

I have a simple question about the shiny slider.

I got a csv file that contains Weeks of a Year and also some other data that im visualizing with a plot. So on Y-Line i got Data, on X-Line i got Weeks.

I'm giving the option that you can choose the range of the weeks by yourself with a slider (f.E week 1 - 75)
now comes my question.
A Year has only 53 Weeks, so by week "75" i mean the week "22" of the next year.
But i cant visualize that at the slider.

Would there be a option, that I can change the slidertext? f.E "Week 1 2020" and last week (75) would be "Week 22 2021"

Here's an image of my slider - all i want to change is the Text shown over the slider:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a minimal reproducible example, i.e. a short, running shiny app that shows your problem. Then it's easier to help you, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the slider `Date` class objects for min/max/value and set `step = 7` so each step is a week, and specify `timeFormat = "Week %U %Y"` to get your desired format. E.g.

```
sliderInput(
  week_input,
  "Select week range",
  min = as.Date("2020-01-01"),
  max = as.Date("2021-06-01"),
  value = as.Date(c("2021-01-01", "2021-03-01")),
  step = 7,
  timeFormat = "Week %U %Y"
)
```

Of course you'll need to modify the rest of your code to expect a `Date` as the input from the slider.

Comment: This is at the moment my UI Code:
 sliderInput("weekinput", "week",11, 75, c(25, 40)),
              uiOutput("slider"),

and my server code:

output$PLOT <- renderPlot({
    filtered <-
      Data %>%
      filter(week >= input$weekinput[1],
             week <= input$weekinput[2]
      )
    ggplot(filtered, aes(week, .data[[input$typeInput]]))

Im using the dployr library for this, will this be a problem?

Comment: I mean, currently you're slider `input$weekinput` is a numeric. With my version it will be a Date. You'll have to make some changes, but they shouldn't be too hard. You'll either need to convert the Date to a number like your old way, or use a Date  column in your data (creating it if you don't already have one).